Master Details Design with Calendar
I have a web page with a table that contained each task of someone for each days of the month.
It's something like this but with 30 column and more tasks



Task
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday




Task 1
2 hrs
1.5 hrs
3 hrs
2.5 hrs
1 hr


Task 2
1 hr
2 hrs
1.5 hrs
3 hrs
2 hrs



And my problem is that this view is not enough detailed for me. I need to implement a way to display details for each of the task. Details that can be either plain text or another table
I want to know why this person spend 2hrs on task 2 on tuesday for example.
I'm not familiar with Ui design or concept and only found some suggestions for Master Details view.

I'm looking for suggestions of how to display the details of the selected cell in the table without lossing this global view of the time spend on each task.

One of the solutions that i found was to add a blank space under the calendar to write all the details:

Is there any better way to keep this global view and display the details?

You should study how calendar applications work. In most of them, when clicking on an event, an editable modal window appears with the main information about its content.


Thanks, I forgot to mention that in somes case my details can be another table
